# Can I divide a 300 ml liquid bottle into three smaller bottles?

Tags: airport-security, domestic-travel

On Domestic Flights in the US, travelers can take a few 100 ml liquid bottles? Can those bottles have the same liquid?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4397/46

Comment: Why not? Why would difference or identity matter?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You can read the TSA's [liquids rule](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule).  Bottles must each be 100 ml or smaller, but I don't know of any rule against having more than one bottle of the same substance.

All your bottles have to fit in a standard one-quart plastic bag.  Three 100 ml bottles should fit in that space, but you may not have a lot of space left for other liquids.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the intent of the rule has less to do with the liquids themselves and more to do with the potential threat of a large quantity of explosive materials. The assumption is that 100 ml of a liquid or low-viscosity explosive substance is not capable of causing enough damage to take down a commercial airliner. Therefore, as long as the container volume is 100 ml or less, they don't really care what you put inside them... as long as it's not an illegal substance.

Comment: Then, of course, you can take up to ten of those, and they also allow you to take empty bigger containers. So you can easily pass 1 liter of the explosive material. Combine several passengers that get together before boarding, and a single passenger can board with many liters of any liquid, within the rules. Most senseless rule ever.

Comment: @MartinArgerami the empty containers loophole is not particularly problematic as it should be impossible to acquire explosive liquids in the secure area of the airport.

Comment: @phoog who says you can't pass the explosive liquid through security inside of ten 100 ml bottles? You didn't really address MartinArgerami's point. And Martin, I can't really say much on your point without going into a diatribe about the idiocy of government. Rules (Laws) don't really have to be sensical when they're enforced at the point of a gun.

Answer (score 0):

## YES, you definitely can...

> **READ MORE** at the following TSA.gov web page for the TSA ***"Liquids Rule"***:  **https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule**

---

### EXCEPTIONS:

```
**Domestic US Flights and Outbound International Flights departing the USA:**

 - medications (does NOT indicate prescription only)

 - baby nourishment (baby food/milk/Similac, etc.)
```

**Inbound International Flights:**

You may carry duty free liquids in secure, tamper–evident bags, more than 3.4 oz or 100 ml in your carry-on bag if:

- The duty free liquids were purchased internationally and you are travelling to the United States with a connecting flight.
- The liquids are packed in a transparent, secure, tamper-evident bag by the retailer and do not show signs of tampering when presented to TSA for screening.
- The original receipt for the liquids is present and the purchase was made within 48 hours.

*Liquids more than 3.4 oz or 100 ml [and] not [placed/packaged] in a secure, tamper-evident bag must be packed in checked baggage.*

Comment: Except the URL you've pointed to doesn't say ANYTHING about whether the bottles can contain the same product, which is the question that was actually asked.